# Force heading and mdframe onto same page

Tags: mdframed

I use `mdframed` to quote the problem set. This is very often done at the beginning of a section, which gives occasionally breaks over two pages, like so:

[image: Page breaking of section and mdframe]

This seems neither useful nor beautiful to me, so I have used `\newpage` to get it onto the same page for today's work. What would be a general way to get them onto the same page automatically?

This is what I use:

```
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[%
    backgroundcolor=black!5,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=black!10,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    skipabove=\topskip,
    innertopmargin=\topskip,
    splittopskip=\topskip,
    frametitle={Problem statement},
    frametitlerule=true,
    nobreak=true,
]{problem}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please always provide an example document (this answer is not tested as no code was provided)

You can use the `needspace` package to force a page break if the heading is going to fall within any specified length of the  bottom of the page.

```
\needspace{3cm}
\section{...}
\begin{mdframed}
..
```